# SQL Server converts last second date to next date

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I am writing this statement in my C# code to assign this value to a Entity Framework class (DB Table) object's variable

```
EmployeeObj.LastDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2023 23:59:59.999");
```

But the `LastDate` saved in the database table becomes "01/02/2023 00:00:00.000"

Why this is happening?

When I change 999 to 997 then it is saved correctly
i.e.

```
EmployeeObj.LastDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2023 23:59:59.997");
```

^ this works fine

Comment: What is your SQL datatype? You might want to check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) `Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds`

Comment: If the column is a `datetime` data type, it's probably a [rounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#rounding-of-datetime-fractional-second-precision) issue.

Comment: Just one of the reasons [Why You Should Never Use DATETIME Again](https://susanibach.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/)

Comment: Thanks you all, now I understand this is rounding issue. My DB column type is "datetime". How to know that its using .000, .003 or .007 accuracy while rounding data ?

Comment: Just Use [datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instead.

Comment: `How to know that its using .000, .003 or .007 accuracy while rounding data ?` - it always is...

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for the help . If you post this as answer, I will accept that which shall help the future people who will face same issue

Comment: Its been asked and answered many many times before... I'm surprised you didn't find it while searching tbh... just delete.

Comment: Please note that the decision to store the "last moment" of a day is often wrong, if you're storing datetime ranges. You'll simplify things a lot if you store an *exclusive* endpoint and use a `<` comparison against it than trying to compute the last moment to allow you to use `<=` or `between`.

Comment: I have to wonder what this data actually represents. What are the chances that something actually happened 1 millisecond before midnight? There's almost certainly a better way to achieve your aim. Or was this just a bit of experimentation?

Comment: @jmcilhinney End-of-Day or `24:00` is an actual business and aviation concept, check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00). `2023-11-14 24:00` isn't the same as `2023-11-15 00:00`. When you search for flights, the web service results can include `24:00` to signify that a flight leaves or arrives at the end of the date, not the next date. Which would mean it would arrive in a different slot, or get charged extra due to the date change. Few libraries support this though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sounds like some people haven't heard of half-open intervals..... which is how end dates *should* be stored. I'm guessing that's what OP's real problem is: use of an inclusive end-date, and trying to prevent it going over another day by using .999